# Gromov-Witten theory of equivariant local projective plane

Tags: gromov-witten-theory, reference-request

> Can I find written explicitly in the literature a formula for the genus zero equivariant Gromov-Witten theory of local $\mathbb{P}^2$?

I understand that the [method of Givental](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9603021) will give the answer, but as far as I can tell he does not treat the case of concave bundles explicitly there, and it would be nice to have an answer free of the mistakes which I am bound to introduce during a calculation.

More precisely, denoting by $\overline{M}_{0,1}(\mathbb{P}^2,d)$ the moduli space of stable maps from genus zero curves with one marked point to $\mathbb{P}^2$, by $ev$ the evaluation map at the marked point, 
and by $\mathcal{E}_d$ the bundle whose fibre at a map $f:C\to \mathbb{P}^2$ is $\mathrm{H}^1(C, f^* K_{\mathbb{P}^2} )$, and working throughout equivariantly with respect to the full torus $T = (\mathbb{C}^*)^3$,

> Where can I find in the literature an explicit formula for 
>   $ev_* \mathrm{Euler}(\mathcal{E}_d) \in \mathrm{H}_T(\mathbb{P}^2)$?

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem in the future: the answer is that you should look in Givental's paper "Elliptic Gromov-Witten invariants and the generalized Mirror conjecture", Thm. 4.2.  (The title tricked me into thinking that nothing useful about genus zero invariants could be in there...)